# jQuery plugin - multiple instantiation

Tags: jquery

I'm asking for help. I have almost clean jquery boilerplate with my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XXw5h/7/

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {


    var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

      function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;


        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        someVal: Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999),

        init: function() {
            self = this;

            aEl = $('<a/>', {  
                href: '#',
                text: this.options.propertyName,
                click: function(e){self._clicked();}
            });

            $(".el1").before(aEl);    
            $(".el1").before("<br/>");    

        },

        _clicked: function(el, options) {
            alert("Random value of el instance:" + this.someVal);
            alert("Property name:" + this.options.propertyName);
        }
    };


    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );

$('.el1').defaultPluginName({
  propertyName: 'el1 link '
});

$('.el2').defaultPluginName({
  propertyName: 'el2 link'
});
```

My problem is that I need multiple instantiation and it's where my troubles begin. I know my question was answered here:

[jQuery plugin multiple instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617019/jquery-plugin-multiple-instantiation)

but I just can't make it work.

When you click at el1 link at linked jsfiddle, I need to show one random number and property of first instance of plugin. When you click at el2 link at linked jsfiddle, I need to show second random number and property of second instance of plugin. Currently it's same for both links.

My question is how to create own options for every instance of my plugin? And then, what is the right way to create my own per instance variables? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I don't see any link, could you double check your fiddle?

Comment: Awww, sorry and thanks for message. Updated, now it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> self = this;
> aEl = $('<a/>', {  
>     href: '#',
>     text: this.options.propertyName,
>     click: function(e){self._clicked();}
> });
> ```

You're assigning to a **global** variable `self` here, which will get overwritten by the second plugin instantiation and only refer to that.

Add the [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to make it a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Bergi's answer is true, you should define `self` as local variable. In addition, I would like to add that you should make `someVal` a function to have random number every time you click on the link, otherwise they will be the same number at init time. So the updated code should be:

```
Plugin.prototype = {

    someVal: function () { 
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999) 
    },

    init: function() {
        var self = this;

        aEl = $('<a/>', {  
            href: '#',
            text: self.options.propertyName,
            click: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                self._clicked();
            }
        });

        $(".el1").before(aEl);    
        $(".el1").before("<br/><br/>");    

    },

    _clicked: function(el, options) {
        alert("Random value of el instance:" + this.someVal());
        alert("Property name:" + this.options.propertyName);
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/XXw5h/8/